Optimal design for large space-based radiators
I like hard sci-fi, but one thing that's almost always missing in hard sci-fi depictions of space ships are the radiators.
I have a vague idea to fix this by making some renderings of spaceships with realistic radiators, and so I'm looking for hard-science information about what those would be likely to look like.
In reality, heat dissipation is a really big deal in space, since the only way you can get rid of heat is by radiating it away. If your spacecraft has all but the simplest of propulsion systems or if it supports a lot of people then it's going to need to get rid of a lot of heat. Realistically, the heat sinks would be one of the most visible aspects of its outside appearance, and might end up dwarfing the rest of the ship.
On the ISS, the radiators look fairly similar to the solar panels - they're just a bunch of white panels held together with metal trusses. But those are tiny compared to what you'd need in your average sci-fi scenario, where you might have gigantic nuclear thrusters or need to support a thousand people living in comfort. The ISS's radiators are also constrained by things like launch volume - they launch folded up and then unfold once in orbit - which wouldn't be a consideration if we're talking about something that's built in space.
I suspect that most spaceships and space stations in a realistic space-based sci-fi setting would have heat sinks that are close to the optimal design, dissipating the most heat possible for the least mass, with no particular constraint on volume. The problem is that I can't find any information on what that design would look like. In an atmosphere optimal heat sinks have fins, but I've no idea if that's still true in a vacuum. I suspect the optimal design might just be one big flat circular sheet, to minimise the amount of heat that gets radiated back onto the radiators, but that could easily be wrong.
So this is a hard-science question, looking for information (with references and/or calculations) about what an optimised space-based radiator would look like, assuming the need to dissipate many orders of magnitude more heat than the ISS.
I should note that while answers at all tech levels are welcome, I'm primarily interested in the "every day" spacecraft that you'd find in an industrialised Solar system, rather than interstellar travel or combat.
I should also note, I'm not looking for alternatives to radiators, or for reasons why a spaceship might not need them. My goal is to visually depict spaceships and space stations with realistic radiators, and so I'm looking for information relevant to what they would look like visually, assuming an optimised design and reasonably large power requirements. I have a physics/maths background.

All the knowledge a lay person might seek on this topic can be found at the the 'bible' of hard SF space travel i.e The Atomic Rockets website The section on radiators is here: [1]: https://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/heatrad.php#id--Heat_Radiators--Radiator_Types--Liquid_Droplet--Triangular_LDR About a quarter of the way down you'll come to a list of potential radiator types but the Radiator section covers everything you might need to know from basic physics through to layout, the pros and cons of different types, radiators and cooling in space combat, the whole works. Set asi

Lovely! This is going to be an enjoyable couple of hours.

Enjoy, its a fantastic site put together by an engineer with a life long interest in bot space flight and (good) SF. Unfortunately I believe he's very ill at the moment but steps have been taken to preserve the site itself in case he's doesn't recover. When you finished with radiators  there's an index at the start  that lays all the sub topics out.

I don't understand why @Mon's answer was converted to a comment. I was planning to accept it after giving time for other answers. Sure, it's based on a reference, but that's what [tag:hard-science] is meant to be about.

Thanks but 'dem are the rules' I guess. I just did what I did because it was far quicker than parroting what someone else took the time to post on a website.  Winchell deserves the credit. I'll get the green tick some other time!

I looked a bit into the link to the The Atomic Rockets website to figure out if a replacable heat sink could be an option (e.g. heat up the the normal waste or regularly collect some ice). Unfortunately the answer is No, there is simply too much heat to use a heat sink as a permanent solution unless you mount the ship on an ice asteroid. Radiators are the only durable solution.

I recommend to also have a look on the Thermodynamics section. The quotes are very fitting.

This is somewhat similar to this (https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/197861/how-much-energy-can-a-space-ship-use-internally-without-overheating) question of mine. The big takeaway of the answer there is that the amount of energy/ heat radiated away scales with temperature to the fourth power. That means, what you mostly need are radiators that can get very hot and have a way to transfer excess heat there. That helps a lot more than size and shape of the radiators.

@quarague you might appreciate the comment in the community wiki answer about radiators for life support vs. for engines. For a life support system it's important to keep it at room temperature, and because of the $T^4$ law that could mean the radiators for life support need to be bigger than the radiators for the engine, which can radiate at a much higher temperature.

I have never understood why SF authors want to get rid of heat in long journey space flights. All the energy you will ever have is in that ship at the beginning of the journey. It ain't going to get any more. There are no filling stations on the way. Throwing out heat into galactic space just does not make sense. The hard science tag automatically dictates that you will get no answer. We do not yet know the science. Heat is vibrating atoms. The trick is to find the scientific method to convert the vibrations to some form of 'substance' that will store this energy.

For example transducing the vibrations into electron flow inside a plasma or in some zero resistance super-conducting coil type tank circuit that is outside the ship (some as-yet-undiscovered variation of the Seebeck Effect), in heatless space.  Think  perhaps a tokamak that is not meant to produce energy through fusion, but to store it in the plasma.

@JustinThymetheSecond what would be the point? You can't turn that energy back into useful work (second law of thermodynamics, the hardest law of hard science there is), so what would you be storing it for? However your heat storage device works it will need to be emptied sooner or later, and unless you're going to land it on a planet and conduct or convect the heat away (for what purpose?) a radiator is the only way to do that.

The supposed 'Three Laws' have done more to restrict physics progress than the Roman Catholic church did in the 14, 1500's.We treat those laws as 'gospel' and have made a religion out of them. They apply only to a limited subset of physics reality, and totally ignore the probabilistic nature of things. The stored energy in this plasma field can obviously be used, that is the entire concept behind nuclear fusion reactors. They obviously demonstrate that heat CAN be 'pumped uphill', the plasma in these reactors was entirely 'built up' counter to any concepts of 'entropy'.

Employment: Needed; great manual dexterity, small hands, tolerance of repetitive work, OK with hot environments, 401K or hotter. Productivity related benefits. Demon preferred.

I'm posting a community wiki answer to make sure the excellent answer originally posted by @Mon gets preserved. That answer was:

All the knowledge a lay person might seek on this topic can be found at the the 'bible' of hard SF space travel i.e The Atomic Rockets website
The section on radiators is here: https://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/heatrad.php#id--Heat_Radiators--Radiator_Types--Liquid_Droplet--Triangular_LDR
About a quarter of the way down you'll come to a list of potential radiator types but the Radiator section covers everything you might need to know from basic physics through to layout, the pros and cons of different types, radiators and cooling in space combat, the whole works.

I guess the answer was converted to a comment for being link-based, so I will include some information and images from the link below.
The document confirms my guess about a big flat panel being the optimal geometry, like the left-hand ship in this image:

(The right-hand ship has alternating panels and mirrors, but that doesn't work thermodynamically so it's best to ignore it.) The document has information about the diminishing returns you get from having more than two fins, like the three-fin design below, which is about 86% of the efficiency of a 2-fin design.

(The document points out that having the fins glow white/yellow hot is unrealistic, because that would melt any material they could reasonably be made of, but glowing red hot is to be expected for many types of engine.)
However, the document also says that the loss of efficiency is much less if the fins have a low aspect ratio, in that they stick out a long way from the ship's body, compared to their length. So you could have a configuration with, say, six long thin fins emanating from the engine, which I think would look pretty cool.
The document also says that you can get some efficiency savings (in terms of dissipation per mass) by putting holes in the fins. So an optimal radiator might look more like a grid of pipes stretching out along a flat plane, rather than a solid sheet. But the document also mentions a trade-off there that I hadn't thought about, which is that larger fins in terms of area means a higher moment of inertia, so the ship would be harder to steer.
There is also a lot of stuff about other kinds of radiator than the obvious solid ones, for example radiators that fire hot droplets through space and collect them again (apparently there are fluids with low enough vapour pressure for that to be possible), or which use dust suspended magnetically in plasma, and various other ideas. These would look completely different from the big metal fins I was originally imagining, but they would still be very large and dominate the ship's appearance.
Another really interesting point is that if your ship has both a life support component operating at room temperature and a ginormous nuclear engine of some kind, then it will almost certainly have two separate radiator systems, and the fins for the life support one might be bigger than the ones for the stonking great fusion drive! This is because of the Steffan-Boltzmann law, which says that a black body radiates heat at a rate proportional to $T^4$. For life support system it's really important to keep it at room temperature, which means the rate of radiation from the fins is really slow. But when the engine is operating you can get away with rejecting heat at much higher temperatures, so those fins will glow red hot and radiate much faster, meaning they don't need to be as big.
Finally, I want to share this amazing pre-production image from 2001: A Space Odyssey, showing a version of the Discovery that has radiators attached to its engines. I'd like to imagine there's a parallel universe in which these made it into the final design, and therefore all the ships in Star Wars had radiators as well, and so today we would be used to seeing realistic radiators in science fiction depictions of space ships. There are plenty of other pre-production sketches from 2001, showing that it was intended to have radiators almost up to the final version.

It's really worth reading that page if you're interested in this stuff, it's a gold mine of information, and if you want to know what high-powered spaceships would really look like it's important stuff to know!

In the Discovery, why couldn't they just build the radiators into that really long tube?

@MikeSerfas it's fictional so there doesn't have to be a reason, but if it was a real ship then doing it that way would add a lot of complexity for little to no benefit. According to the book those radiators glow red hot when it's leaving Lunar orbit, and having red hot radiators running parallel to a structural beam is going to present some engineering challenges. Also, the radiator fins can radiate from both sides, which wouldn't be the case if they were built into the hull, so they'd have to be twice as big. It's built in space, so there's no particular disadvantage to it looking like that.

Interestingly, the earlier designs for the Discovery had the fins run parallel to the beam as in the first two images. This makes sense, as it would minimise thermal transmission from the fins to the beam. I suspect the reason they were changed in this later version is to make them look as radiator-like and un-wing-like as possible so that viewers can tell what they're meant to be.

Worth noting a big advantage of the angle accordian like radiators is they can be folded to reduce damagem they are stronger/stiffer and you can control how much heat they radiate much better, which is why modern spacecraft use them. you are not always trying to get rid of the same amount of heat afterall. ////////\ https://www.jstor.org/stable/44612020

@John the ISS radiators don't fold up again after deployment, they're only folded up during launch. You don't need to fold them up to control the heat flux, because they radiate proportional to $T^4$, so you can just pump less heat into them and they'll radiate less because they're colder.

@N.Virgo true, but there is no reason they could not fold up unused sections. I was thinking more of a consideration for combat craft, where the need for rapid replacment or minimizing area of a short time would be important. but the other considerations apply, use less material for same stiffness

Neutrino pair production.
The best answer under all sane circumstances was posted by Mon above, citing the Atomic Rockets Website.  That website says "If you stayed awake during Physics 101 class you'll know that the blasted laws of thermodynamics say there are only three ways of getting rid of waste heat."  They link to a general Wikipedia article on heat transfer, but I think it's reasonable to assume that they mean thermal radiation, thermal convection, and thermal conduction.
But there is a fourth way, known from white dwarfs and neutron stars.  You build particles from scratch out of pure energy and disperse them together with some quantity of thermal energy which depends on the temperature and your degrees of freedom.  Now that's very expensive, so we want to use very cheap (light) particles, which means neutrinos.  Nobody really knows just how light the lightest neutrinos are, but we might not need to spend that much free energy to get rid of thermal energy.
The article "The neutrino emission due to plasmon decay and neutrino luminosity of white dwarfs" describes the decay of plasmons (quanta of electromagnetic field in a plasma) into neutrino-antineutrino pairs.  There is quite a bit of math involved which I haven't followed in any detail, but what sticks out is that we see various formulae dependent on the sixth, seventh, or eighth power of plasma frequency, which presumably means electron plasma frequency.
In stars this is simply calculated; I don't know how much your sci-fi aliens can manipulate that number.  As described in an astronomy.SE post, the rate of cooling by neutrinos can be much faster than the rate of cooling by photons, at least in a neutron star.  It seems an interesting lead for research.
I should clarify that in terms of appearance, this sort of heat sink would not be visible.  The plasma needed to emit this energy would be at a high temperature close to the site of waste heat production, and neutrinos would be emitted from that location almost undetectably (by currently available and unclassified technology, at least).  Some auxiliary heat sinks might still be needed to deal with heat escaping from this plasma, though it would be preferable to keep it insulated from the rest of the ship entirely.
Mobile radiators.
If the ship has residual cooling needs, or the approach above doesn't pan out, the next tactic should be drone radiators.  This idea is based on the Atomic Rockets website suggestion of spraying molten particles for cooling; but that idea is unworkable because the ship can't both maneuver and cool itself.  Let's do better.
The radiator we want is a thin, hollow ball of quartz or corundum.  Inside we've painted it with synthetic mucopolysaccharides (fake fish slime), and we've partially filled it with pure water.  Outside, we've etched a thin layer of electronics onto the sphere, over which we've put another sphere of anti-solar cells.  Over those, we have a layer of a switchable reflector.  To the outside, we append an ejectable battery as a keel.  (The device fills the battery but does not need it to function)
The radiator drones can navigate by changing various portions of themselves from reflective to absorptive.  The asymmetric radiated heat gives them a slight thrust from light pressure, which permits slow maneuvers around the ship.  For emergency maneuvers they can open a pinhole valve and permit some of their water to vent.
Your ship has an oral groove in front, which receives the cooled radiator drones.  They glide through the evacuated transport channel system in the ship to dock at a point where they are moored to cool down their surroundings potentially to sub-freezing temperatures.  As drones approach the desired temperature in each area, they are moved onward until they reach the hottest places to be cooled at the rear.  When the pressure of steam reaches maximum safe level, they navigate out the ship's proctodeum (exit to unenclosed space).  Traditional finned heat sinks surround this region as a backup measure, providing some life support cooling in situations where the drone radiators need to be left behind.
The heat sinks very slowly circle the ship, using their radiation pressure to provide a centripetal force, until they are ready to enter the oral groove again.  But in emergency situations, by releasing their stored water and using their stored electricity to heat it if necessary, they can develop enough thrust to create shield formations to defend the ship against light and particle beams or missiles.

thats still just radiative heat transfer. radiative heat transfer is not just photons.

@John - thermal radiation is electromagnetic radiation, at least according to Wikipedia.  But apparently other sources do describe radiative heat transfer in terms of "radiation", which is not necessarily electromagnetic despite a strong implication.  It was misleading to search for this content due to a large number of sites now attaching brief wrong definitions to the top of search results - it appears the days of doing "research" with a web search engine have just about come to an end.

Hmm, so from the links I get that if you heat something with a small surface area up to the order of 100,000 K then it can radiate via neutrinos faster than it radiates via electromagnetic radiation, and then it wouldn't need much surface area because matter is transparent to neutrinos. But if your heat sink is at 100,000 K then it means your ship's power system has to be able to operate at temperatures even higher than that. This is much higher than the boiling point of any material, so this seems unlikely. (Not to mention thermodynamic efficiency issues when the cold reservoir is that hot.)

@N.Virgo - this is the case in stars.  I simply have no idea whether it is possible for people to manipulate the frequency of a plasma somehow to get neutrinos from a cooler plasma.  Neutrinos are at least possibly light enough to be generated from the thermal energy of much cooler substances.

In any case, note a modern-day tokamak can have a temperature of 150 million K, so even 100000K is more than cool enough for an efficient heat engine.  Provided you can insulate it.

Not only insulate it but also extract work from the temperature difference between $\sim 10^6,K$ and $\sim 10^5,K$. This might in principle be possible using magnetic fields without touching it, I don't know. I agree that it could be possible for something to emit thermal neutrinos at a much lower temperature, but I think this is unlikely. Whatever the thing is, its neutrino emissivity needs to be so much higher than its EM emissivity that it can offset the difference between a $T^4$ and a $T^8$ scaling law, which basically means it needs to be opaque to neutrinos but transparent to light.

although there's probably a constant in front of that $T^8$, analogous to the Steffan-Boltzmann constant in front of the $T^4$, which would mean there's an absolute limit to the thermal neutrino flux that can be emitted at a given temperature. That probably makes a low temperature neutrino radiator physically impossible. I agree that a high temperature one might actually be plausible though.

I'll make it easy, what form of heat transfer is beta radiation. Forms of heat transfer are just macroscale models used for calculation. radiative heat transfer is heat transfer un attenuated by a vacuum. does the Stefan-Boltzmann equation model it, then its radiative heat transfer. Don't fall victim to confusing the model for the thing.

@N.Virgo Equation 10 from the paper has a T^9 in it, but that's based on the case that the plasma frequency is much smaller than the temperature.  If I don't have it flipped, I think the sink would want the plasma frequency to be as high as possible, so hopefully that isn't a limitation.  I don't immediately see why there would be a Staffan-Boltzmann like constant here limiting neutrino production any more than there is one limiting how much rocket exhaust you can put out.

@MikeSerfas I don't really know, I'm mostly going by the astronomy.SE link you posted. But if it's a form of thermal radiation it should behave similarly to the Steffan-Boltzmann law, which says a black body radiates at a rate of $\sigma T^4$ per unit area. This is a maximum - you can radiate less than that by not being an ideal black body, but you can never possibly radiate more. It's different from rocket exhaust because it's thermal - rocket exhaust is far from equilibrium so doesn't have the same kinds of limit.

@N.Virgo - Is pair production a form of thermal radiation?  I asked perplexity.ai and it said no, FWTW.  Once the neutrinos are created, they must take up heat, and they move away.  If there's any limit on the process it has to be a limit on how much pair production you can do, which I have no idea about.

@MikeSerfas most microscopic processes can either be thermal or not. It's not the microscopic details that make it thermal or not, it's whether it's happening statistically as a result of a temperature difference. In the case of white dwarfs neutrino pair formation must be thermal else it couldn't be responsible for cooling them down, and similarly, if its purpose on a spaceship is to reject heat then you'd want it to be as close to thermal as you can get it. You could pump netrinos out faster than that, but that would take work, such that you'd get no net thermodynamic benefit from it.

@N.Virgo - if we look at it just as a matter of thermodynamics, then we're talking about the risk that a neutrino happens to hit a particular spot in the plasma and heat it.  Now if the plasma absorbs neutrinos (I can't wrap my head around that - what is it that turns some H+ and e- into a neutrino sunblock?) I suppose this would happen... 70 billion times per square centimeter per second??   I'll admit, I have no idea how to work this one out.

I don't know either, without going deeper into the references than I want to. But you've hit the nail on the head there really - the plasma would need to be, if not opaque to neutrinos, then at least able to interact with the neutrino field enough to emit them thermally at an appreciable rate, and it's hard to imagine how to achieve that. In a while dwarf or a neutron star we're talking about something a lot different than a plasma, and I guess it interacts with neutrinos just because it's so dense and there's so much of it.

Something that the provided website states, but which the designs don't seem to properly take into account, is the possibilities inherent in heat pipe design. Heat pipes aren't complicated. They push heated material out to a radiator where it cools, and then draws it back for another round.
There are a three reasons why this is significant. The first is that it doesn't limit the radiative area to being close to the heat source. The second is that the shape of the radiators doesn't need to carry the heat, only radiate it. A third is that the alignment of the radiators doesn't need to be fixed.
That's one of the key design features of the ISS radiators. They're basically flat panels with tubes running through them. They're connected to pipes that run all over the space station. You could basically push the heat to wherever you want it to go. If you aren't under thrust, you could even pump it to independent structures a distance from your ship.
You wouldn't want them to be of fixed orientation. You benefit from being able to swivel them so that they're perpendicular to the local solar radiation, keeping them in each others' shadows. You could even gain efficiency by turning one so that it completely overshadowed the rest of them.
This general concept, however, violates the Rule of Cool. Unless you're writing something that uses the radiators as an environmental hazard, there's really no reason to get this fancy/non-fancy.

I might be weird, but I think thermal management is cool. I like the idea of a realistic space based environment where the challenges are completely different from the ones in air or water, and I like the idea of spacecraft that look radically different from the aircraft-in-space that we usually see

@N.Virgo, Good for you! I was on a convention panel where we discussed the writing of sci-fi, and my argument was that you needed to include the things that were particular to space, like vacuum and weightlessness. Star Trek introduced a culture of Office Buildings In Space, and we kinda forgot that those things were important until Expanse reminded us.

Your idea of a big circular sheet is pretty close to ideal, there are really only a couple of design factors at play for peak efficiency. I am assuming there are practical engineering materials limits in place in your sci-fi setting so radiator temperatures are going to be in a more or less fixed level, a higher temperature will radiate more heat, but you can't go higher than the melting point of your structural materials.
Surface Area
The amount of heat radiated is proportional to surface area, more surface equals more heat transferred.  so you want to maximize area while minimizing the material used.  This means large flat panels.  A circle can be the most efficient, but for practical manufacturing reasons, structural support reasons, or geometric reasons these may be rectangular.
Geometry
The radiation emitted from your radiators goes in all directions from the radiators, meaning a flat plate will radiate in all directions covering 180 degrees, or 360 degrees if it radiates from both sides.  This will however be reabsorbed by any portion of the spacecraft that is within the line of site of the emitting surface.  Some key search terms here are 'view factor' or 'spatial arrangement'. In general this means that for optimal efficiency your space craft structure and radiators will be arranged along the same flat plane to minimize reabsorption of radiated heat.
Note: There will not be banks of parallel fins, fins optimize convective heat transfer by increasing area to atmosphere, they do less than nothing in space, they will just radiate back on themselves, no parallel fins.
Reducing Conductive Transfer
The radiators are part of an overall heat transfer strategy, there are parts of the craft producing heat and parts you want to stay cool.  The radiators are going to have some kind of pipes to move heated fluid into them getting them hot to radiate the heat.  It is unhelpful if these hot radiators are physically connected to parts you want to stay cold as the heat will be conducted through the structure of the ship back those areas.  You need insulation, but vacuum is a pretty good insulator, this is why most radiators are on struts or other supports not directly connected to the main ship.
Other Considerations
Your craft is going to undergo accelerations and these radiators will have to have structural supports to deal with the stresses involved and most likely they will need to be symmetrical along the acceleration axis to balance the craft.

Maybe the design proposed by John Ringo in The Vorpal Blade book of The Looking Glass series be of some use?

The answer was a new and innovative heat sink. Installed (...) were
two extensible cylinders of, essentially, glass with some iron and few
other trace elements thrown in. Heat would be pumped into them until
they were boiling hot. The mixture of silicon dioxide (glass), and
other elements were perfect reservoirs for thermal energy until the
molten tubes reached near the vaporization state. At that point, the
boat would have to find a deep space, very cold, spot and "chill". To
extend the heat capacity of the tubes they were surrounded in
liquid-metal heat pipes that flowed out to the underside of the
spaceship. The heat pipes would radiate some of the energy into space
and the liquid would cool and be flowed back over the molten glass
tubes. This only bought time; eventually the thermal load became far
more that the thermal management system could handle and "chilling"
would be necessary.

The whole series is written with as much hard-science as possible, which is why it is co-authored, as well as consulted heavily with scientists. I do recommend it wholeheartedly for that technobabble all throughout the adventures of the A.S.S. Vorpal Blade.

It doesn't work. You can't pump heat uphill into a reservoir without a cost in energy, which means more waste heat to pump into that reservoir. With any reasonable material, a reservoir of reasonable mass quickly exceeds the temperature of any reasonable reactor and you can't get enough power to keep everything else cool. At best, you might be able to carry enough thermal mass to absorb brief spikes of heat production, allowing your reactors to deal with it over a longer amount of time.

@ChristopherJamesHuff - energy expenditure is a given. I didn't see an efficient heat exchange system that's passive, like ever. Also, in a space vessel EVERYTHING requires cooling. But I see the point, i think: it would maybe work for everything except the engines. My answer is: maybe. It all depends on propulsion method and materials used. If we finally get somewhere really efficient with Dirac materials, then... all bets are off. Besides, Vorpal Blade goes forth thanks to Little Black Box, it will take some time to get there in reality.

Expending more power than your power source to supply to pump waste heat into a bunch of ultra-hot heat sinks is not a given. The answer is not "maybe", it's "no".

@ChristopherJamesHuff - can you give me an example of a reaction power source that DOES NOT require active cooling, please? ISS certainly does all cooling, including for the EPS, via active cooling systems (ATCS). Also, you are distorting the description - in the solution proposed "ultra-hot heat sinks" are that way only in two situations: right before and at the initial phase of "chilling". In any other case they range from super cold to hot. Then cycle repeats.

There are no power sources that use active cooling. Active cooling is a method for disposing of waste heat, it consumes power. The ISS doesn't use any kind of reactor or other thermal system, it is solar powered, and its radiators are for disposing of internal waste heat, not part of its power system. And there is no reason for the heat sinks to ever get "ultra-hot", you would need to "chill" before they even approached the temperature of the reactor. They would in fact need to chill when they got hot enough they could no longer condense low-presssure steam effectively.

@ChristopherJamesHuff whether it works or not depends on whether the heat that needs to be dissipated is hotter than the heat sink temperature. If the ship's power source is a reactor that operates at 1500K then the heat sink could be at 1000K if you want. You extract work from the difference between 1500K and 1000K, and you could use that work to pump heat from the cabin into the heat sink if you wanted, even though the cabin is at 295K. However, you're right that that would be costly, and it would be more practical to have a secondary heat sink at less than 295K as well.

Molten glass near its boiling point isn't 1000 K, it's more like 3000 K, and a reactor is closer to 1000 K than 1500 K. And while in general you only need a heat sink colder than the reactor if you have a heat engine that isn't dependent on a phase transition, Carnot efficiency will get very low as they heat up, resulting in power output dropping to nothing. And for the specific case of the Vorpal Blade, you had a naval reactor system that needed to actually condense steam at low pressure.

This is an engineering Frame Challenge
The reality of space radiators, as has been discussed in the comments and linked articles, is that they are not very effective. Relying on their operations to reject a massive amount of heat would not be feasible. Rather, we need to design them out.
You don't need powerful radiators. You need good ship design, shielding, and active cooling
For this answer, I will assume the ships are powered by a fusion torch engine. The first misconception of your question is that the engine core would be housed inside the ship. Indeed, if that was the case, you would need massive radiators to reject the excessive heat. But thats is a bad ship design. Rather, the torch cores and fuel lines would be mounted in the aft of the ship and gapped from the habitable areas. The engine would be mounted to the main ship using materials that are poor heat conductors like tungsten, or other exotic choices.

[Titanium] has a low density and a thermal conductivity of 17 W/mK. Hence, it is a poor conductor of heat.

Metals with poor conductivity
The area between the engine and the main habitat would be heavily shielded with MLI and Aluminized Mylar to reflect any EMR from the torch.
Power for the ship would be generated elsewhere with a design like voyager's Radioisotope Thermoelectric Generators and mounted on the exterior of the habitat so as to not conduct heat inside.
Lastly, these ships do not have to fly forever until they make port. In the same way that they would have to refuel their reaction mass, they would refuel their cooling mass. Liquid helium and ammonia are already used to cool the JWT Cryocooler and the ISS respectively. If the habitat overheats, you can evaporate your coolant into space to cool it down.
As per comments from OP, this question really boils down to engine design. We are currently capable of providing power and cooling a habitat that does not have a fusion torch attached to it (ISS, Skylab, etc..)
So the question really is: Can we design a fusion torch that doesn't melt the habitat?
Probably.
The tech is theoretical, but the science is solid. Rather than quote the whole article, I will just link it here. It addresses all of the questions in the comments. Here is the relevant conclusion on the article:

Finally, keep in mind that the propulsion technology described here is not specific to the setting of the Expanse. It respects physics and you can introduce it to any setting where real physics apply. In other words, it is a ready-made and scalable solution for having rapid travel around the Solar System without much worry about propellant, radiators, radiation shielding and other such problems

https://toughsf.blogspot.com/2019/10/the-expanses-epstein-drive.html?m=1
This a late edit, but people have asked why I chose to frame this answer as if the OP was asking about a torch drive. I think Project Rho sums it up quite nicely:

Have you simply had it up to here with these impotent little momma's-boy rockets that take almost a year to crawl to Mars?
Then you want a herculean muscle-rocket, with rippling titanium washboard abs and huge geodesic truck-nuts! You want a Torchship! To heck with John's Law, who cares if the exhaust can evaporate Rhode Island? You wanna rocket with an obscenely high delta V, one that can crank out one g for days at a time. Say goodby to all that fussy Hohmann transfer nonsense, the only navigation you need is point-and-shoot.
It is a pity that torchships are currently science fiction. But they are unobtainium, not handwavium. Ain't no law of physics sez they are impossible, we just don't know how to make one. Yet.
And like all good unobtainium, even though we can't build it yet, we can calculate what it can do just fine.


I didn't assume that at all. The torch drive is going to need a radiator regardless of where it's housed, and so is the life support system and whatever powers it. An RTG with an RTG sized radiator is good for keeping a radio alive, but if you want to keep a significant number of people alive then the power requirements and hence the radiator will need to be bigger. Expendable coolant just isn't going to cut it for a mission with more than minimal power requirements, as there isn't a substance with a high enough heat capacity.

Anyways I don't think this meets the requirements for the [tag:hard-science] tag.

@N.Virgo Why would the torch need a radiator? It already is a massive, directed radiator. It also needs to be kept hot to achieve fusion. Also, the links I provided are "empirical " proof of shielding and cooling subsystems already in use. The JWTs cryocooler is rated for 10+ years of operation.

It needs a radiator because nothing is 100% thermodynamically efficient, so not all of the energy it generates can be turned into thrust. The excess needs to be disposed of in order to maintain the correct operating temperature. If the waste heat is allowed to just build up instead then the engine would quickly melt. Again, the question is about power requirements many orders of magnitude greater than the ISS, let alone the JWST, which has much smaller power requirements than that.

@N.Virgo your questions of heat and confinement for energy are addressed in the linked article I added to my answer.

Torch drives are kind of in the realm of "potentially plausible fantasy". I don't think they're very realistic, but if you want them to exist for plot reasons, and if you want them not to need radiators for aesthetic reasons, then you can probably come up with some plausible sounding numbers to give you what you want. But I prefer not to start from "what do I want it to look like" but "what do I think it would actually look like, given the best scientific knowledge available". From that perspective I don't think torch drives would exist, and if they did I think they would have radiators.

@N.Virgo Umm, then what is powering your ship? What is generating all that heat that needs yo be radiated out? Your question asks for hard science, but you reject the most likely candidate for advanced propulsion. The ship design in this answer mirrors every example in the wiki and in the article I linked.

@N.Virgo You don't like the answer because it negates the need for elaborate and massive heatsinks. But the reality is that radiators in space are ineffective. Either we design them out of the engines, or we don't build them at all.

@JustAnotherUser even is you somehow get no heat from the engines, you still need radiators for the crew, living spaces need ot be heated for humans and living bodies produce heat. and that assuming your ship does not have weapons or anything generating heat. then of course you have problems like sunlight. also putting the engine on a boon does not mean it still does not need a radiator, not many engines can work if the whole engine is at exhasit temprature.

Hiya @John, we spar again :) Correct on all counts. However, with the exception of a high yield engine and weapons, which I completely overlooked, we already have temp management systems available. On the ISS which has been working for decades without cooking an astronaut into a bratwurst. So is the question: What is the radiator design of the ISS? Nope, It's: would we need radiators if I stuck a massive nuclear reactor to my space ship? If so, what would they look like?

"poor heat conductors like aluminum": aluminum has the fourth highest thermal conductivity of the metallic elements, behind only silver, copper, and gold, and not by a huge factor. And coolant doesn't magically make heat go away, the JWST and ISS use radiators.

@ChristopherJamesHuff The JWST has a massive sun shield and an 8ft radiator. This proves my point. It is much more important to prevent the heat from getting to protected areas, than it is to try to remove it later using elaborate radiators.

@ChristopherJamesHuff Also, I removed Aluminum from the proposed materials as you are correct.

JWST does not "prove your point", it serves as a direct counterexample. The heat must be removed, and radiation is the only practical means of doing so.

@ChristopherJamesHuff You know the apollo vehicles had heaters right? You know the JWST radiator is only necessary to keep the IR equipment ridiculously cold right? You know that space is cold right? You know that just about everything is a black body radiator (including the hull) right? Humans in a spaceship with no additional means of heating up would freeze to death.

The Apollo vehicles had radiators as well, and were largely kept warm by waste heat produced by internal equipment. Only parts of the JWST need to be that cold, and it requires radiators despite having a power budget of only 2 kW. Passive cooling is very limited, humans in a spaceship with no means of disposing of waste heat beyond radiation from the hull would most likely bake.
